# How to avoid CoreData objects being assigned in 2 different CloudKit record zones?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I started the application with CoreData and everything worked great.
I then migrated to CloudKit and things started going wrong. For the last few weeks I am regularly haunted by an error

> error: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate
> _requestAbortedNotInitialized:: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x2830280e0> - Never successfully initialized and cannot execute
> request '<NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x282a88460>
> A1AD2329-41F4-44F6-BEF6-452A62C7B2C0' due to error: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Object graph corruption detected.
> Objects related to '0xb925efc0b75e6e2c
> x-coredata://7974B0E0-2A86-4F52-B0B3-72F8FAE3AFB1/ShotCoreData/p2447'
> are assigned to multiple zones: {(
> <CKRecordZoneID: 0x28075f1b0; zoneName=MyCustomZone, ownerName=**defaultOwner**>,
> <CKRecordZoneID: 0x28077f870; zoneName=com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone, ownerName=**defaultOwner**>
> )}}

I have a fairly complex CoreData setup, which looks something like this:
Master

- Category1

  - Child1

    - Child2

      - Child3 (which will contain an identifier reference, UUID String, to Category2)
- Category2

The code to save objects from app version to CoreData looks something like this:

```
func saveObject(_ newObject: AppModel) {
    let newCoreObject = Category1()
    newCoreObject.child1 = convertChild1(from: newObject.child1Models)
    saveContext()
}

private func convertChild1(from source: [Child1AppModel]) -> [Child1] {
    source.compactMap {
        let coreModel = Child1AppModel($0)
        coreModel.child2 = convertChild2(from: source.child2Models)
    }
}

private func convertChild2(from source: [Child2AppModel]) -> [Child2] {
    // Create CoreData object and assign properties mapped from AppModel version
}
```

It looks to me like sometimes when creating Child2 or Child3 objects, they get assigned to multiple zones, both the default zone as well as the custom zone (following Category1 assignment), leading to CoreData graph corruption and the data gets locked locally, no longer syncing remotely.

So I am now left with 2 questions:

1. Why is this happening? Is there a trick I'm missing to ensure new objects only get allocated to the correct zone? I am currently relying on CoreData "getting it" and don't perform any manual assignment on individual items.
2. Once such a corruption occurs, how would you migrate the data safely? Should I manually parse every object type from the default zone (com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone) and ensure if present in custom zone, I'll delete from here? Or is there a more generic option to fetch impacted objects and remove clones (ie: fetch items that are in ZoneA & ZoneB, then remove them from ZoneB)?

Comment: I've been backwards and forwards with this issue for the last 2 months, so whilst I don't know whether this is the final solution, a temporary solution is checking whether CoreData objects are assigned to a CKShare, and assigning them if they're not. Weird flow, but temporarily solves it (wish I knew better why).